# Bash script to open multiple git-bash windows at certain sizes and locations?

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

Is it possible to write a bash script that opens six git windows open in a 2x3 grid, with each window being 400x400px. See pic. Is this possible? I'm running Windows 10. Let's assume my display is my 2nd display, 1600 x 1200 resolution with a portrait orientation.

Something like this but with dimensions and x, y locations and times six:

`alias bash='/git-bash.exe & > /dev/null 2&>1'`

[image]

Comment: Would you be happy with a `powershell` script that does this? Powershell plays much nicer in a windows environment than bash does.

Comment: @Lenna Sure. Ultimately it would be nice to have it as a quick launch in my task bar, but I could probably save it as a `.bat` right?

Comment: @Lenna For example I have a file called `empty.bat` that force empties my Recycle Bin. `PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command Clear-RecycleBin -Confirm:$false`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a powershell script:

```
﻿Function Set-Window {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.

        .PARAMETER ProcessName
            Name of the process to determine the window characteristics

        .PARAMETER X
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

        .PARAMETER Y
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

        .PARAMETER Width
            Set the width of the window.

        .PARAMETER Height
            Set the height of the window.

        .PARAMETER Passthru
            Display the output object of the window.

        .NOTES
            Name: Set-Window
            Author: Boe Prox
            Version History
                1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015
                    - Initial build

        .OUTPUT
            System.Automation.WindowInfo

        .EXAMPLE
            Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru

            ProcessName Size     TopLeft  BottomRight
            ----------- ----     -------  -----------
            powershell  1262,642 2040,142 3302,784   

            Description
            -----------
            Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe
        
    #>
    [OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ProcessName,
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height,
        [switch]$Passthru
    )
    Begin {
        Try{
            [void][Window]
        } Catch {
        Add-Type @"
              using System;
              using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
              public class Window {
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

                [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
              public struct RECT
              {
                public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
                public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
                public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
                public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
              }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    ProcessName = $ProcessName
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}
& "$env:ProgramFiles\Git\bin\git-bash.exe"
get-process git-bash | foreach { 
  Set-Window -ProcessName $_ -X 400 -Y 4000
}
```

Set-Window function is from
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527

Comment: What would I need to add to save it as a `.bat` file so I can run it with a double click?

Comment: Save it as .ps1 file and then double click

Comment: Double click it as a .ps1 opens it in Notepad. It's not a big deal. I need to tweak the script anyway because running it in PowerShell opens only one git-bash instance.